# How to use useEffect() without performance degradation

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a React Native app where, on one screen, I have a useEffect hook that constantly fetches data from a site and updates my local variable with that data (see below for a simplified example). The problem I am running into though is that this is killing the performance of my app. Even if you leave this screen, the app is sluggish.

The issue is no doubt caused by the countless calls to the URL to get the data & constantly resetting my local variable with the data. I tried using a dependency array with the hook, but if I do that it doesn't continually update, it only updates on the first load of the screen and I need it to update whenever there is a change (whenever new data is available).

Is there a way to do this so that I constantly get any updates from the remote source but don't slow down my app?

```
const [retrievedData, setRetrievedData] = [{}];

useEffect(() => {
    let fetchedData;

    fetch(
      'https://site-with-data.com',
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setRetrievedData(processData(json.events));
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
```

Comment: Do you need to constantly fetch it? Or could you fetch only in certain situations?

Comment: Constantly polling over HTTP for new data isn't efficient. If you really need real-time data, you'd want a websocket or some other sort of long-lasting connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `useEffect` doesn't have a dependencies array (the second argument), it will run on every render. That is why you are making so many calls.

If you need to update the data real-time, the first question you must answer is: how will the client know the data has changed in the server?

One way you could make the server notify the client is by using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). A WebSocket creates a bidirectional connection between the client and the server, and the server can notify the client whenever anything changes. Other than that, you could also use a technique called ["long polling"](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/http-long-polling/) or ["server-sent events"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

But any of these three solutions would require you to change your server (in addition to your client).

## Quick fix: limit the update frequency to "refresh every N seconds"

The quick and dirty alternative without changing the server is just to decide a frequency (e.g., update every 5s) and go with it in the client.

Example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {

    fetch(
      'https://site-with-data.com',
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        setRetrievedData(processData(json.events));
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
    
  }, 5000); // update every 5s

  return () => clearInterval(intervalId);

}, []); // add to this array any variable that affects the fetch (e.g., URL)
```

Which number of seconds should you use? That will depend on each case. To decide that, evaluate both UX and server load.

Comment: Thanks so much for this super detailed response! This is super helpful. I really really appreciate it.

Comment: Cool! Just one last note: be mindful of the cleanup part of the `useEffect`. Namely, when the user navigates away, a `fetch` request may have already been dispatched and not yet have returned. This could make the `setRetrievedData` be called when the component is not mounted anymore, leading to "leak" errors. You should handle that accordingly.

Comment: Can you use websockets if you have a backendless app? Currently I am running everything else through firebase so building out a backend for this would be a big lift for this solve (I think).

Comment: Great point on the leak - I actually had a warning about that and was trying to track it down. As you can probably tell, I am new to react native :)

Comment: Actually, firebase, if you use `onSnapshot` of firestore, already notifies the frontend on any change. This solution would do without websockets.

Comment: Ah so I would but unfortunately this one data source comes from another random place, so wouldn't be able to use onSnapshot. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can create WebSockets in firebase. With firebase, you are kind of limited by what they offer off-the-shelf. Perhaps, if all of your users are fetching the same info, you could create a Cloud Function that gets the data from that random place and pushes it to a firestore. The clients would then get notifications from the firestore. This would reduce the load on the random place.

Comment: That's probably my best bet. All users use the same data so that's a good solution. Thanks again for all of your help!